# I can't communicate with SQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I try to connect to MySQL, it doesn't show the success status of user added, i get the following error :

```
{"message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}
```

I don't understand what "method" it is talking about...the POST i am doing with POSTMAN ? some help would be greatly appreciated !

So i change my code to put the MySQL() in the POST method, i still get the same error....

Here is my "api.py" code :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class CreateUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            # Parse the arguments
            parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
            parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
            parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password to create user')
            args = parser.parse_args()

            _userEmail = args['email']
            _userPassword = args['password']

            return {'Email': args['email'], 'Password': args['password']}

            mysql = MySQL()
            # MySQL configurations
            app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
            app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'itemlistdb'
            app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

            mysql.init_app(app)

            conn = mysql.connect()

            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.callproc('spCreateUser',(_userEmail,_userPassword))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
               conn.commit()
               return {'StatusCode':'200','Message': 'User creation success'}
            else:
               return {'StatusCode':'1000','Message': str(data[0])}

        except Exception as e:
            return {'error': str(e)}

api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i use a stored procedure to write the values in db, the procedure is spCreateUser, here is the code of it :

```
BEGIN

if ( select exists (select 1 from tblUser where UserName = p_username) )
THEN

select 'Username Exists !!';

ELSE

insert into tblUser(
UserName,
Password
)
values
(
p_Username,
p_Password
);

END IF;
```

END

Comment: If you edit the code like this you can't make the conn.commit()....

I need to change the cursor.

replace : 
cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
with :
conn = mysql.connect()

cursor = conn.cursor()

Answer (score 0):

> If a resource is invoked with an unsupported HTTP method, the API will return a response with status 405 Method Not Allowed.

I am guessing your trying to view your resource on browser so you having this error. If you want to see resource on browser it must support http `get` method.

```
class CreateUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?,?)",(email,password))
    def get(self):
        #...
```

And one more thing `QueryDb` method would not called by self you have to call it in one of http methods.

Comment: I am just trying to post an user in DB with POSTMAN but i can't do it...

Comment: Then run your sql in `post` method. I write an example in answer

Comment: But my stored procedure is supposed to do it when i POST an email and a password with POSTMAN....

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved everything...Might be useful for others :

So first i put the name of the function with a "post" not a "Post".

Then i was getting the following message :

"A setup function was called after the first request was handled"

The solution to get rid of that is to disable debug mode....

so here is the code working :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class CreateUser(Resource):
     def post(self):
        try:
            # Parse the arguments
            parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
            parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
            parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password to create user')
            args = parser.parse_args()

            _userEmail = args['email']
            _userPassword = args['password']

            #return {'Email': args['email'], 'Password': args['password']}

            mysql = MySQL()
            # MySQL configurations
            app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
            app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'itemlistdb'
            app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

            mysql.init_app(app)

            conn = mysql.connect()

            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.callproc('spCreateUser',(_userEmail,_userPassword))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
               conn.commit()
               return {'StatusCode':'200','Message': 'User creation success'}
               cursor.close()
               conn.close() 
            else:
               return {'StatusCode':'1000','Message': str(data[0])}
               cursor.close()
               conn.close()

        except Exception as e:
            return {'error': str(e)}

api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```